# Distribution of Markov process (Selinger et al., 2007)

Tags: calculus

In Selinger et al., (2007), the authors described  that for a Markov process, the distribution of $t = \text{ISI}$ (interspike interval) follows the exponential form

$f(t) = \frac{1}{\tau} \exp(-t/\tau)$

where $\tau$ is the mean ISI. The distribution of $x=\ln(\text{ISI})$ therefore follows the form:
$g(x) = \frac{1}{\tau} \exp(x - \frac{1}{\tau}\exp(x))$

I would really appreciate if someone explain me how do they obtain $g(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking "how do I find the pdf of $\ln(X)$ if $X$ has the pdf $f(t)=1/\tau \exp(-t/\tau) 1_{(0,\infty)}(t)$?". To do that, note that $P(\ln(X) \leq t)=P(X \leq e^t)=F(e^t)$, where $F$ is the CDF of $X$.  So the pdf of $\ln(X)$ is $g(t)=\frac{d}{dt} F(e^t)=f(e^t) e^t$. Note that this trick works if and only if you are taking a monotone transformation of your random variable.